# How to delete older logs in ELK to give each application a certain disk quota

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am trying to use the ELK (Elasticsearch+Logstash+Kibana) stack in the following scenario:

I have about ten applications that send their logs, through Logstash, to a single Elasticsearch cluster.

Some of these applications naturally generate more logs than others, and, sometimes, one of them can go 'crazy', because of a bug, for instance, and, thus, generate even more log entries than it normally does. As a result, the disk space available in the cluster can be unfairly 'taken' by the logs of a single application, leaving not enough room to others.

I am currently managing the available disk space through Elasticsearch Curator. It runs periodically, as it is in the crontab, and deletes older indices based on a disk usage quota. When the disk space used by all indices exceeds a certain limit, the oldest indices are deleted, one by one, until the sum of the disk space used by them all is within the specified limit again.

The first problem with this approach is that Elasticsearch Curator can only delete entire indices. Hence, I had to configure Logstash to create one different index per hour, and increase their granularity; thus, Curator deletes smaller chunks of logs at a time. In addition, it is very difficult to decide how often Curator should run. If applications are generating logs at a higher rate, not even one-hour indices may be enough. Secondly, there is no way to specify a disk usage quota for each different application.

Ideally, Elasticsearch should be able to delete older log entries by itself whenever the indices reach a certain disk usage limit. This would eliminate the problem of defining how often Curator should run. However, I could not find any similar feature in the Elasticsearch manual.

Would anybody recommend a different approach to address these issues?

References:
http://www.elasticsearch.org
https://github.com/elasticsearch/curator

Answer (score 4):

Try using index lifecycle management, which is available in ELK stack 6.6 newer version.

Please check this link:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/getting-started-index-lifecycle-management.html

This will create new index when size goes beyond 2GB or 1d, and it will delete 1day back data.

```
PUT _ilm/policy/stream_policy
{
  "policy": {
    "phases": {
      "hot": {
        "actions": {
          "rollover": {
            "max_size": "2GB" ,   
            "max_age": "1d"
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "min_age": "1d",
        "actions": {
          "delete": {} 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can delete your old logs ( filebeat logs in this example )

```
curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/filebeat-2016*?pretty'
```

Comment: It helped me. Thank You @abhishek-goel

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of indexes and shards, elasticsearch will have more difficulty keeping them open (you'll get memory errors).  With 10 applications, you'll have a ton of shards.  I prefer fewer indexes for this reason.

I think what you might want is a way to delete the "surplus" records when you get too many for a given application.

Imagine a small script that would run and count the number of documents by type and day, and then delete those that exceeded your limits.

Here's how to count by type and date:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_type": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_type"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_date": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "@timestamp",
            "interval": "day",
            "order": {
              "_key": "desc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

And the results look like this:

```json
  "aggregations" : {
    "by_type" : {
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "type1",
        "doc_count" : 900000,
        "by_date" : {
          "buckets" : [ {
            "key_as_string" : "2015-02-13T00:00:00.000Z",
            "key" : 1423785600000,
            "doc_count" : 300000
          }, {
            "key_as_string" : "2015-02-12T00:00:00.000Z",
            "key" : 1423699200000,
            "doc_count" : 200000
          }, {
            "key_as_string" : "2015-02-11T00:00:00.000Z",
            "key" : 1423612800000,
            "doc_count" : 400000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Now you can loop through the types and per-date counts, figuring out what dates you'd like to delete.  In the example above, if you only wanted 500,000 entries for "type1", then you'd know to delete entries from 2/11/2015.

You can use "[delete by query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html)" to get rid of those documents.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **curator** for this task. It is a utility from elastic.

Docs are available at [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/index.html)

It is simple to install:

```
pip install elasticsearch-curator
```

Use is simple to.

-for first, create config file, for example, with the next content:

```
---
# Remember, leave a key empty if there is no value.  None will be a string,
# not a Python "NoneType"
client:
  hosts:
    - 127.0.0.1
  port: 9200
  url_prefix:
  use_ssl: False
  certificate:
  client_cert:
  client_key:
  ssl_no_validate: False
  http_auth:
  timeout: 30
  master_only: False

logging:
  loglevel: INFO
  logfile:
  logformat: default
  blacklist: ['elasticsearch', 'urllib3']
```

-next, create action file with the following content:

```
---
# Remember, leave a key empty if there is no value.  None will be a string,
# not a Python "NoneType"
#
# Also remember that all examples have 'disable_action' set to True.  If you
# want to use this action as a template, be sure to set this to False after
# copying it.
actions:
  1:
    action: delete_indices
    description: >-
      Delete indices older than 45 days (based on index name), for logstash-
      prefixed indices. Ignore the error if the filter does not result in an
      actionable list of indices (ignore_empty_list) and exit cleanly.
    options:
      ignore_empty_list: True
      disable_action: True
    filters:
    - filtertype: pattern
      kind: prefix
      value: logstash-
    - filtertype: age
      source: name
      direction: older
      timestring: '%Y.%m.%d'
      unit: days
      unit_count: 45
```

At final you can run task with the **curator**

```
curator [--config CONFIG.YML] [--dry-run] ACTION_FILE.YML
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix - logstash **[throttle](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-throttle.html)** filter, where one sets a key based on application name.

Another solution: set "index" parameter in **elasticsearch** output to specify application name like (pseudocode) "logstash-%{appname}-%{date_format}", then run curator with "--prefix" set to "logstash-appname" and --disk-space to whatever you like. Haven't tested that myself though.

Finally, there are many ways to monitor disk space in (almost) real time, but what I usually use is  http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#SPACE-TESTING

P.S. of course having multiple "logstash-xxx-" will be problematic to use with Kibana